# activiti API for task candidate users

Tags: java, activiti

I would like to get the **candidate users** for a **task** but can not find any API in

`org.activiti.engine.TaskService`
or
`org.activiti.engine.task.TaskInfoQuery`

Is there any API or do I need to use `taskService.createNativeTaskQuery()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up filtering the candidates, `users` will hold a list of all the candidate user ids.

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
List<IdentityLink> links = taskService.getIdentityLinksForTask(taskId);
for (IdentityLink link : links) {
    if (IdentityLinkType.CANDIDATE.equals(link.getType())) {
        users.add(link.getUserId());
    }
}
```